# Why can I not view foreign language characters in my mysql DB?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mojibake

I am inserting the following characters into my DB: **汉字 / 漢字**

This is the meta tag on the page that is inserting the characters:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I have altered all the columns in my table that is holding the characters to be **utf8_unicode_ci**

The foreign characters show up like so in the DB: **æ±‰å­— / æ¼¢å­—**

When I use a sql statement to display those foreign characters on a page, they display correctly again as: **汉字 / 漢字**

I am guessing I have some setting that is not correct in my DB, since it stores it correctly, but does not display it correctly.

What can i do to make the foreign language characters to display correctly in my DB?

**EDIT:** Here is my insert:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO orders (foreign_characters)
        VALUES (?)';

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['foreign_characters']);
$inserted = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: What are you using to view the data in your DB? Are you querying over the command line using the MySQL client?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a web interface? Perhaps phpMyAdmin isn't setting the Content Type HTTP header, so the characters aren't being displayed ok in the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the connection to the database also UTF-8 encoded?

Give this a try: right after connecting to the mysql database, run the following query.

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

This should do the trick (see [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html)). (Yeah, you have to do this everytime you connect.)

BTW: don't just rely on the `<meta>`-Tag, send the appropriate HTTP header.

Comment: thanks, but I am a bit confused. Where do I put that query? Within the same query that is inserting the foreign characters into the DB? Also, what is the appropriate header I should be sending and how should I write that?

Comment: I added my insert query so you can see what I am doing, as I am not sure where to add the query you suggested.

Comment: Do i add the query you suggested as a separate query or part of the insert query I am already running?

Comment: Great! It worked wonderfully! I added $conn->query('SET NAMES utf8'); Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your message on time. You did the right thing: a new, seperate query right after you established the connection.